# clear text view value while onclick is performed

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I do have the clear function but still the value is not clear. May i know how to solve this problem ?

```
public class abc extends MenuActivity implements OnClickListener{


    EditText et3;
    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.safebox_flow);


        et3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText02);
        et3.setText(String.valueOf('0'));
        et3.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v){
        //Also here check the edittext02 id thats set in the xml layout
        if(v.getId() == R.id.EditText02){
           et3.setText("");
        }
    }


}
```

- I have to double click it only can clear.

Comment: either setting the value to null do this  et3.setText(""); and check if you are invoking the onClick methord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below part of your code goes into the onCreate method.

```
//Here make sure **EditText02** is the id that you have declared in XML
et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText02);  //input type for edittext02 is number

et3.setOnClickListener(this);


public void onClick(View v){
       //Also here check the edittext02 id thats set in the xml layout
       if(v.getId() == R.id.EditText02){
          et3.setText("");
       }
}
```

Also ensure that your class implements OnClickListener

```
//example below
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
```

Please comment below if you still face problems. Hope this helps!

Comment: yea, everything should be fine. but still have to double click it only clear the text value .

Comment: could you update the question with full activity code and also the xml part of the edittext.

Answer (score 0):

just try :

```js
et3.setText("");
```

instead of :

```js
et3.setText(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 et3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText02);

    et3.setOnClickListener(this);

   @Override 
    public void onClick(View v){
           if(v.getId() == R.id.EditText02){
              et3.setText("");
           }
    }
```

Comment: I put it already, still same. hmm it have the message " the application may be doing too much work on its main thread "
Is that affect my code ?